# can't load extension manager typo3

Tags: typo3

In typo3 6.1, i've met an issue to load extension manager.
Seeing the console, it was du to an error 500 by loading extension manager by mod.php

```
GET http://localhost:8888/typo3_src/typo3/mod.php?M=tools_ExtensionmanagerExtensionmanager 
error 500
```

Is that extension manager not included into module folders ?

Comment: fix it switching in PHP5.4, version 6.1 doesn't work well under version 5.4 of php

Comment: 500 means internal server error. Check the server logs to find out what happens.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line in your apache httpd.conf file, and restart server

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Typo3 installation you just need or required below settings.

Inside php.ini configuration Change the value.

```
post_max_size = 80M
max_execution_time = 240
```

Append the belows lines in php.ini file

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 400
```

Go to http.conf Add below lines at bottom

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
   ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```

Comment: So these are all just some arbitrary settings? Xdebug, Windows, ..? You don't even know the context of the actual problem.